# Testing class which returns big dictionary

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have simple class with the public `build` method I want to test. Currently I assert all values it returns in every test. Is it a good practice or I should write one test for static values and in other tests only check values which change depending on input?

**Implementation**

```
class FiltersAttachment:
    TYPE_OPTIONS = [
        {"text": "All types", "value": "all"},
        {"text": ":link: Webpages", "value": "web_pages"}
    ]

    STATUS_OPTIONS = [
        {"text": "Available / Unavailable", "value": "all"},
        {"text": ":white_circle: Available", "value": "available"},
        {"text": ":red_circle: Unavailable", "value": "unavailable"}
    ]

    @classmethod
    def _filter_options(cls, options, selected):
        return list(filter(lambda t: t['value'] == selected, options))

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, check_type='', status=''):
        return {
            'fallback': 'Filters',
            'callback_id': 'resource_filters',
            'color': '#d2dde1',
            'mrkdwn_in': ['text'],
            'actions': [
                {
                    'name': 'resource_type',
                    'text': 'Type',
                    'type': 'select',
                    'options': cls.TYPE_OPTIONS,
                    'selected_options': cls._filter_options(
                        cls.TYPE_OPTIONS, check_type)
                },
                {

                    'name': 'resource_status',
                    'text': 'Status',
                    'type': 'select',
                    'options': cls.STATUS_OPTIONS,
                    'selected_options': cls._filter_options(
                        cls.STATUS_OPTIONS, status)
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Tests**

```
class TestFiltersAttachment(TestCase):
    def assert_attachment(self, attachment):
        self.assertEqual(attachment['fallback'], 'Filters')
        self.assertEqual(attachment['callback_id'], 'resource_filters')
        self.assertEqual(attachment['color'], '#d2dde1')
        self.assertEqual(attachment['mrkdwn_in'], ['text'])

        type_action = attachment['actions'][0]
        self.assertEqual(type_action['name'], 'resource_type')
        self.assertEqual(type_action['text'], 'Type')
        self.assertEqual(type_action['type'], 'select')
        self.assertEqual(type_action['options'][0]['text'], 'All types')
        self.assertEqual(type_action['options'][0]['value'], 'all')
        self.assertEqual(type_action['options'][1]['text'], ':link: Webpages')
        self.assertEqual(type_action['options'][1]['value'], 'web_pages')

        status_action = attachment['actions'][1]
        self.assertEqual(status_action['name'], 'resource_status')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['text'], 'Status')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['type'], 'select')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['options'][0]['text'], 'Available / Unavailable')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['options'][0]['value'], 'all')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['options'][1]['text'], ':white_circle: Available')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['options'][1]['value'], 'available')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['options'][2]['text'], ':red_circle: Unavailable')
        self.assertEqual(status_action['options'][2]['value'], 'unavailable')

    def test_all_type_selected(self):
        attachment = FiltersAttachment.build(check_type='all')
        self.assert_attachment(attachment)

        selected_type = attachment['actions'][0]['selected_options'][0]
        self.assertEqual(selected_type['text'], 'All types')
        self.assertEqual(selected_type['value'], 'all')

    def test_all_status_selected(self):
        attachment = FiltersAttachment.build(status='all')
        self.assert_attachment(attachment)

        selected_status = attachment['actions'][1]['selected_options'][0]
        self.assertEqual(selected_status['text'], 'Available / Unavailable')
        self.assertEqual(selected_status['value'], 'all')
```